# How to focus an element only if it isn't currently focused?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The reason I want to do this is because there's some unwanted styling behavior going on when I click on an already focused input. I'd rather it only apply when I first focus it.

I have a basic useRef that holds my inputEl, and I want it so that clicking on the icon (which is a sibling) next to the input element will focus the relevant field, but only if it isn't already focused (if it's already focused, it should do nothing).

So I tried to put the following onClick on the Icon element.

```
onClick={() => {
  if (document.activeElement !== inputEl.current) {
    inputEl.current.focus();
  }
}}
```

This condition doesn't work because every time a click happens, the activeElement clears and defaults to the body and so the check fails and I focus again. Not 100% sure why that happens. For some context, the project is bootstrapped by CRA and the icon with this onClick is a Font Awesome React icon. There's nothing notable about the input element except that it has a ref property of inputEl. As I'm using useRef, you probably guessed, but this is inside of a functional component.

I can probably think of some pretty convoluted ways to solve this issue but I'll defer until I get an answer to see if there's a cleaner way. I was thinking maybe setting some state value after focusing, using that in the check and using a useEffect to return the state value to null when the element unfocuses or something like that. Is that an okay idea? Is there a simpler method I'm missing?

Edit: I think I phrased the issue poorly. What I'm trying to solve is the problem that every time I click the icon, it briefly unfocuses the field before refocusing it, which causes my focus transitions to happen on every click.

Comment: Have you tried `onFocus` rather than `onClick`?

Comment: @JamieDixon the element itself is not supposed to receive focus so I can't use onFocus. It's basically a magnifying glass inside my search bar. It's supposed to focus the field, not itself. But clicking it unfocuses the field before refocusing it causing styles to be applied again. That's the problem I want to solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change focus happens when mousedown event fires on element, you can use mousedown event handler to prevent change the active element.

```
onMouseDown={(e) => {
  if (document.activeElement == inputEl.current) {
   e.preventDefault();
  }else{ /*Do focus on input*/ }
}}
```